# hours for Kaymakli and Derinkuyu Underground Cities

Tags: turkey, opening-hours, cappadocia

I'll be in Cappadocia on Nov 27 and was thinking about visiting Kaymakli and Derinkuyu Underground Cities. To make the most of the time and to facilitate better planning I'd like to know what their hours are. In particular, what time do both of them close at?

I want to see Göreme while the sun is out but for these underground cities I'm thinking daylight isn't quite as important.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entrance fee for Derinkuyu and Kaymaklı underground cities is 42 turkish lira and they're open till 17:00.

Official websites:

https://muze.gov.tr/muze-detay?SectionId=DKY01&DistId=DKY

http://dosim.kulturturizm.gov.tr/muze/56

Comment: Do you know what the "Box Office Summer / Winter Closing Hours" are talking about on that website?

Comment: they are summer / winter hours for museum's ticket sales.